# Super simple binding example

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to do a simple binding but I'm having some problems. I have a text block and a button. The textblock is binded to a property called "word". When you press the button the value of word changes and I want to automacally update the text block. This is a classic example, please explain me what I'm doing wrong:

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{
     public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _word;

        public string word
        {
            get { return _word; }
            set
            {
                _word= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(word);
            }
        }

        private void change_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            word= "I've changed!";
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion


    }
}
```

And my XAML with the binding:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,152,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding word}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="change" Content="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="change_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are raising a `PropertyChanged` event for a property named `I've changed!`, because you pass the *value* of the property `word` to `RaisePropertyChanged`. You need to pass the *name* of the property instead:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("word");
```

This answer assumes that the data context is set correctly. If not, you need to fix that too:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed that "" before. How do I set DataContext? I've tried to "this.DataContext;" before  InitializeComponent(); but it doesn't let me do that.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, that worked! I'm ready now to go further and learn some real binding. BTW, how do you bind some property like that but in other class? (Not the code-behind MainWindow). For example if I have Data.cs class separated with that word property?